# Force close on Phone , but no force close on AVD

Tags: android, http, post, manifest, logcat

I'm trying to parse some JSON data through an HTTP request.I don't get a force close on my AVD ( on my PC ) however I do get one on my phone !

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.database;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class post extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   HttpResponse response= postData();
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   if(entity != null) {
       try {
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

 }



public HttpResponse postData() {

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {        
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI("http://192.168.2.4/test.php"));
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return response;
    }       


}
```

Here's my **manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.database"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".FilePickerActivity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".Dynamic"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".post"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the LogCat entry for my phone :

```
03-24 10:36:16.772: D/dalvikvm(5134): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-24 10:36:17.282: E/Trace(5134): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-24 10:36:17.322: E/dalvikvm(5134): Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache
03-24 10:36:17.322: I/dalvikvm(5134): Unable to open or create cache for /data/app/com.example.database-1.apk (/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.database-1.apk@classes.dex)
03-24 10:36:17.322: D/AndroidRuntime(5134): Shutting down VM
03-24 10:36:17.322: W/dalvikvm(5134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41794300)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.post}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.post
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.post
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
03-24 10:36:17.362: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     ... 11 more
```

How could I solve this ? Many thanks!

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall your app on the device. That's step one.

Comment: Most importantly, this will FAIL on any newer (4.x+) Android devices, because you are running a network operation on the UI thread. Google NetworkOnMainThreadException for more info.

Comment: @323go Yes, it runs on 2.3 but not on 4.0! , How could I get rid of this problem ?

Comment: You'll find dozens of questions and answers with code on that topic here on SO. Just search for NetworkOnMainThreadException. You need to do the http request off the UI thread, either by using an `AsyncTask` (easiest) or by spawning a worker thread.

Comment: Theres also showing that dex directory is not writable, a permission denied chhange permission to the folder . If u fail after making networkonmainthread exception cleared.